# Is it possible to do multiple port forwarding with one ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I can now forward one port 8080 to the remote port 80 by `ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 user@host.com`, Is it possible to do multiple port forwarding with one ssh connection?

Comment: no. a connection is the unique combo of local ip:port and remote ip:port. if you want multiple ports, you'll need multiple connections.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so there is also no possibility to make it in some file?

Comment: Yes you can. Just add as many `-Lsrc_prt:dst_host:dst_prt` arguments as you like. You can also enable the SOCKS proxy as explained by @Eugene below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called dynamic port forwarding and if both the SSH server and SSH client support this, you configure your clients to use the SSH client as a SOCKS proxy and the SSH does the rest. In this case one "SSH connection" (in fact SSH connection carries multiple independent channels "inside") is used to connect to multiple destinations.

Comment: What would be the command line to make it happen? It would also be useful to know how to check if both sides support it.

Comment: More information, please!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use `-L` option for each port to be forwarded.

Example:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 -L 7070:localhost:70 user@host.com
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a link to the documentation to explain how it answers the question.